# Primary domain SSL not working, but wildcard subdomains are working

Tags: domain-name-system, ssl, certificate

I have a domain through AWS Route 53,

the Primary domain was secured via `letsencrypt` methods, but were not working for any wildcard / subdomains...

I tried to redo the cert with the `*.example.com` domain and the DNS TXT verification method in the records.  This worked on my endpoints that are GeoDNS routed to their particular instances, i.e. `fr.example.com` and `us.example.com` ... but now when I go to my primary domain `example.com` it now says it's not secured (anymore), and much of my code referencing this primary domain errors because of `"invalid cert"`.

When I load this primary domain via Chrome browser,  it reports "Not Secure", and when I click it, to see the `Certificate: (Not Secure)` and I'll click on that, the details pop up, shows my `*.example.com` domain, but lit up green saying that domain IS secure. ...?

In Safari it says `*.example.com certificate name does not match input.`

Any Ideas whats wrong?  How can I secure my primary domain with the wildcards being secured as well?

Comment: You need to have both names on the cert.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The wildcard name on the certificate only matches the subdomains. To secure the "naked" domain, you need to add that name separately to the Subject Alternative Name list.

Some of the restrictions in regards to wildcard certificates are explained in [this post](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/acme-v2-production-environment-wildcards/55578).

> Wildcard certificates
>
> The V2 API supports issuing wildcard
> certificates. To request a wildcard certificate simply send a wildcard
> DNS identifier in the newOrder request. Under Let’s Encrypt’s policy,
> wildcard identifiers must be validated by a DNS-01 challenge, so order
> authorizations corresponding to wildcard identifiers will only offer a
> DNS-01 challenge. DNS names in certificates may only have a single
> wildcard character, and it must be the entire leftmost DNS label, for
> instance `*.example.com`. A single certificate can have wildcard DNS
> names for multiple base domains, and can also mix in non-wildcard
> names.
>
> Orders that contain both a base domain and its wildcard equivalent
> (e.g. `*.example.com` and `example.com`) are valid. In that case, there
> will be two authorization objects in the order for `example.com`,
> one of which represents the wildcard validation and one of which
> represents the base domain validation. Redundant entries will produce
> an error. For instance, and order containing both `*.example.com` and
> `www.example.com` would produce an error since the wildcard entry makes
> the latter redundant.

And in reference to wildcard certificates in general, while [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_certificate#Example) is not a reliable source to quote, the example given there is accurate.

> A single wildcard certificate for `https://*.example.com` will secure
> all these subdomains on the `https://*.example.com` domain:
>
> - `payment.example.com`
> - `contact.example.com`
> - `login-secure.example.com`
> - `www.example.com`

...

> Because the wildcard only covers one level of subdomains (the asterisk
> doesn't match full stops), these domains would not be valid for the
> certificate:
>
> - `test.login.example.com`
>
> The "naked" domain is valid when added
> separately as a Subject Alternative Name:
>
> - `example.com`
>
> Note possible exceptions by CAs, for example wildcard-plus
> cert by DigiCert contains an automatic "Plus" property for the naked
> domain example.com.

Comment: Thanks... I was using an older version of ```certbot```, after update to newer version I was able to ```-d *.example.com example.com``` in the parameters... Updated the cert in my server's config files and it was good to go.

Thanks again!

Comment: just to clarify, that would be `-d '*.example.com' -d example.com` - the `-d` must be repeated for each domain & the `*` means the wildcard request needs to be in single quotes to stop the shell expanding it to file names!